# Combine columns into one column separated by a character apply to all rows

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I would like to combine all the columns of an existing xlxs file into one column separated by a `|`

Input

```
10000         1201 - 1201      Premium Ice Cream    EA     76840485116    EA
```

Needed Output

```
10000|1201 - 1201|Premium Ice Cream|EA|76840485116|EA
```

I have an Excel Formula that does the job

```
=Sheet1!A2&"|"&Sheet1!B2&"|"&Sheet1!C2&"|"&Sheet1!D2&"|"&Sheet1!E2&"|"&Sheet1!F2&"|"&Sheet1!G2
```

Is there a way to apply the formula to all rows with a python script?

I've tried to use openpyxl the code below is the closest I've came to a solution.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'Filename.xlsx')
sheet_ranges = wb['Sheet1']
ws = wb.active  
ws["A1"] = '=Sheet1!A2&"|"&Sheet1!B2&"|"&Sheet1!C2&"|
           "&Sheet1!D2&"|"&Sheet1!E2&"|"&Sheet1!F2&"|"&Sheet1!G2'
wb.save("Filename.xlsx")
```

It currently combines the second row and puts into the A1 cell. There is over 1800 rows. 
I would like to apply the formula to all rows and place the result on a new sheet.

I'm obviously a beginner with coding so any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can read excel like this using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',header=None)
```

Having this dataframe:

```
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
1  a  b  c
2  a  b  c
3  a  b  c
4  a  b  c
5  a  b  c
6  a  b  c
```

You can do this:

```
#be sure to do this of you have any column that isn't character
df[0]=df[0].astype(str)

new_df=pd.DataFrame(df[0]+'|'+df[1]+"|"+df[2])
print(new_df)

       0
0  a|b|c
1  a|b|c
2  a|b|c
3  a|b|c
4  a|b|c
5  a|b|c
6  a|b|c
```

and you can save it like this:

```
new_df.to_excel('filename.xlsx')
```

Comment: This does not work if  columns are not of string type

Comment: Yes but in this case, they are string characters. Also, you want the characters to be strings after the transformation so you have to make them as type string either way.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I run the second part of your code I get an error:  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'       So I added quotes like this: newdf=pd.DataFrame("df[0]+'|'+df[1]+'|'+df[2]") when I run it  I get - ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!  I'm I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmmm you have to type for every column df[0]=df[0].astype(str) after reading the file

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I tried the line but I must be implementing it wrong. I am still getting the ValueError: Dataframe constructor not called! error Link to the code:       https://pastebin.com/YM4NdtYM

Comment: Remove the double quotes you added inside the pd.dataframe and you are ready :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `apply` functionality:

```
df.apply(lambda x: '|'.join(x.astype(str)), 1)
```

Input

```
    0       1            2                  3   4           5
0   10000   1201 - 1201 Premium Ice Cream   EA  76840485116 EA
```

Output (only 1 row)

```
'10000|1201 - 1201|Premium Ice Cream|EA|76840485116|EA'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty odd request but pretty easy to do and no need to go through Pandas which, while a great library, is overkill here.

```
ws1 = wb.active
ws2 = wb.create("New Sheet")

for row in ws1.iter_rows(values_only=True):
   vals = "|".join(row)
   ws2.append(vals)
```

Comment: I am getting an error "NameError: name 'values_only' is not defined" When I run this code https://pastebin.com/C9fNqRwD. Am I implementing it wrong?

Comment: you are totally right. Pandas is overkill but since OP tagged it a valid possibility. I would be interested in some timings here because you are iterating over rows which is probably way slower than using pandas alternatives. Nevertheless, this is the best solution if working with small number of rows.

Comment: This will definitely be faster than Pandas because it has to load everything into a dataframe (columns) and then back to a worksheet (rows). Pandas has recently switched to using openpyxl internally for reading. Some openpyxl timings are included in the documentation.